# Layout Xml and image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I build layout xml with two images and put as the LinearLayout backgrund an image too.
the problem is that my top image start 10 px under the main screen and then i saw the top of the LinearLayout  background image.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/hazmanag" android:layout_gravity="top">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/uph" 
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/coupon" android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you say it starts 10px under the main screen are you talking about the Title Bar?

Comment: I have tha main screen, under the status bar the background image is shown,and only after 10-20 px from the statusbar the first image is shown

Comment: I would try specifically setting the margins.

Comment: If u dn't mine Can u Tell your pblm clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "50dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/uph" 
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
```

You have defined android margins in all directions Top, Bottom, Left and Right so you can place the object anywhere in the screen!